# Send As a Delegate or a Distribution Group by default

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

We modified the code from this tutorial to allow us to change default send on behalf address for two mailboxes. https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/setfromaddress.htm#quickinstall

It works perfectly in new window reply but doesn't work in reply pane.

What could be the issue?

Here is the code:

```
Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set objInspectors = Application.Inspectors
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set objMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
        If objMailItem.Sent = False Then
            Call SetFromAddress(objMailItem)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub SetFromAddress(objItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    If objItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "info@domain1.com" Then
        For i = 1 To Session.Accounts.Count
            If Right(Session.Accounts(i).DisplayName, Len("@domain1.com")) = "@domain1.com" Then
                  objItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = Session.Accounts(i).DisplayName
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To Session.Accounts.Count
            If Right(Session.Accounts(i).DisplayName, Len("@domain2.com")) = "@domain2.com" Then
                  objItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = Session.Accounts(i).DisplayName
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If

End Sub

'Uncomment the next 3 lines to enable Outlook 2013/2016/365 Reading Pane Reply
Private Sub myOlExp_InlineResponse(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Set objMailItem = objItem
    Call SetFromAddress(objMailItem)
End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to add. Using Outlook 2019 with Exchange 2016. There are two accounts. Each account can send as account's domain's shared mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Inline reply won't fire the `Inspector.NewInspector` event. You need to use `Explorer.InlineResponse` event. `Explorer` object (assuming you only use one Explorer throughout the Outlook session) can be retrieved from `Application.ActiveExplorer`.

Comment: SentOnBehalfOfName is changed correctly in the debugger but remains unchanged in the outlook. Is this an outlook bug?